# MRTK hand tracking does not work properly with Oculus Link

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I am creating a VR game in Unity.
I am having a problem with hand tracking not working properly with PCVR (.exe build) only.

The detailed situation is as follows

- I have developed a game using Unity, MRTK, and Oculus Integration, running on Oculus Quest2.
- When playing the game via Oculus Link with a PCVR(.exe) build, the following situation occurs.

  - Hand tracking works correctly in the scene immediately after startup.
  - When hand tracking is performed after the scene transition, the hand mesh probably appears at (0, 0, 0) and does not move.
  - The Dynamic Bone Collider attached to the hand is working, so it does not seem that the hand coordinates are not tracked completely.
  - The controller works fine both after startup and after transition.
- Hand tracking works fine in the APK build and in the mode where I press the Play button in Unity.

The version is as follows

- Oculus Desktop App: 38.0
- Oculus Quest2: 38.0
- Unity: 2021.2.7f1
- Oculus Integration: 38.0
- MRTK: 2.7.3

Comment: Unfortunately we don't officially support using MRTK with Oculus Link yet. There is a open issue about it: [Officially support Oculus Link for our Oculus Quest story. #9504](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/9504), you can track it in the GitHub project, since that is where the issue updates would be coming once we get something further to share.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but hand tracking now works.

Removed the following #if UNITY_EDITOR and #endif in OVRSkeleton.cs > Update.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        if (ShouldInitialize())
        {
            Initialize();
        }
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by commenting out that code snippet it is possible to use hand tracking on a PC build using OVRCameraRig and Oculus Integration?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).